# Is it not possible to use HTML entities in a title attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, html-entities

[image]

The above screengrab is from Firefox. The cursor is hovering over the yellow spot at the left hand side of the image. It is an `<img>` element (well actually it's an image together with an image map containing a single circular `<area>` element, but I assume this distinction is unimportant) that has been created and styled in JavaScript, including the application of a title attribute (constructed by cutting and gluing strings). How can I get this to behave and show the intended character, an en dash, instead of `&ndash;`? It works for innerHTML (the text "Barrow-In-Furness" in the top middle-left is a div that was also created using JavaScript, and its innerHTML set.)

Edit: In response to question of Domenic: Here is the JavaScript function that builds and applies the title attribute (in addition to performing other jobs):

```
var StyleLinkMarker = function (LinkNumber, EltA, EltI) {
    var AltText = LocationName[LinkStart[LinkNumber]] +
                  " to " +
                  LocationName[LinkEnd[LinkNumber]];
    if (!EltA) {
        EltA = document.getElementById("link_marker_area" + LinkNumber);
        EltI = document.getElementById("link_marker_img" + LinkNumber);
    }
    if (LinkStatus[LinkNumber] === 9) {
        var CanBuyLinkCode = BoardPreviewMode ? 0 : CanBuyLink(LinkNumber);
        if (CanBuyLinkCode === 0) {
            EltI.src = ImagePath + "icon-buylink-yes.png";
            AltText += " (you can buy this " + LinkAltTextDescription + ")";
        } else {
            EltI.src = ImagePath + "icon-buylink-no.png";
            AltText += " (you cannot buy this " + LinkAltTextDescription;
            AltText += CanBuyLinkCode === 1 ?
                       ", because you aren't connected to it)" :
                       ", because you would have to buy coal from the Demand Track, and you can't afford to do that)";
        }
    } else if ( LinkStatus[LinkNumber] === 8 ||
                (LinkStatus[LinkNumber] >= 0 && LinkStatus[LinkNumber] <= 4)
                ) {
        EltI.src = ImagePath + "i" + LinkStatus[LinkNumber] + ".png";
        if (LinkStatus[LinkNumber] === 8) {
            AltText += " (orphan " + LinkAltTextDescription + ")";
        } else {
            AltText += " (" +
                       LinkAltTextDescription +
                       " owned by " +
                       PersonReference(LinkStatus[LinkNumber]) +
                       ")";
        }
    } else {
        throw "Unexpected Link Status";
    }
    EltA.alt = AltText;
    EltA.title = AltText;
};
```

`LocationName` is as follows:

```
var LocationName = [
    "Barrow&ndash;In&ndash;Furness", "Birkenhead",                "Blackburn", "Blackpool",
                           "Bolton",    "Burnley",                     "Bury",     "Colne",
                   "Ellesmere Port",  "Fleetwood",                "Lancaster", "Liverpool",
                     "Macclesfield", "Manchester",             "The Midlands", "Northwich",
                           "Oldham",    "Preston",                 "Rochdale",  "Scotland",
                        "Southport",  "Stockport", "Warrington &amp; Runcorn",     "Wigan",
                        "Yorkshire"
];
```

Comment: Are you sure the `&ndash;` isn't encoded twice like: `&amp;ndash;`

Comment: How are you setting the title attribute? The following works fine: `<span title="test&ndash;test">test me</span>`

Comment: @Mark: I am confident that it is not double-encoded. In particular, if it were double-encoded, I should expect the bold Verdana text in the top middle-left of the image also to display the HTML entity literally, instead of displaying correctly the intended character. That is because the content of the div is created from the same JavaScript string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't setting the title *attribute*,  you are setting the title *property*, which expects text and not HTML (although the `setAttribute` method also expects a text string).

Generally speaking, when dealing with DOM manipulation, you provide text and not HTML. `.innerHTML` is the notable exception to this rule.

Comment: I see. How may I set the title attribute?

Comment: By blasting away the entire contents of the parent element and replacing it using innerHTML. This is not a good idea. Get your data in text format instead of HTML format. (You could, although I wouldn't recommend it as an approach, set the `innerHTML` of a `span` and then read the `data` of the `textNode` that will be the `firstChild` of that element … but it is better to get the data without HTML encoding from the source)

Comment: I was able to make it work by using UTF-8 text instead of HTML. I had expected that the literal ampersand in one of the other elements of LocationName would cause the page to fail to validate, but it would appear that some magic happens to turn it into an entity. Is there no way to convert text to and from HTML entities within JavaScript? It seems surprising that it should be so.

Comment: You have some HTML which you give to the browser. The browser turns it into a DOM. JavaScript then operates on the DOM and doesn't care that it started out life as HTML, so entities are meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easy way to convert from HTML to text:

```
function convertHtmlToText(value) {
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    d.innerHTML = value;
    return d.innerText;
}
```

Your code could then be updated to this:

```
EltA.title = convertHtmlToText(AltText);
```

Comment: This is an incredibly practical solution, thank you! It's a pity there's no native way to do it, but there is something elegant about this method.