# Set an HTML img title attribute using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

UPDATE: Got the title to pull properly but in Internet Explorer the title of the image is not showing up. Works in Firefox and Chrome. I cannot get my head around it, I'm talking about this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
    <i><strong><a href="__URL__" target="_blank">PDW Status: </a></strong></i>
    <a href="__URL__" target="_blank"></a>
    <a href="__URL__" target="_blank"><br/></a>

    <a href="__URL__" target="_blank">Green</a>&#160;-
    <img id="Green" class="ms-rtePosition-4 ms-rteImage-2 ms-rteStyle-Emphasis" alt="lightgreen1.jpg"
    src="__URL__" style="margin: 5px;"/></em>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;

    <a href="__URL__" target="_blank">Red</a>&#160;-  
    <img id="Red" class="ms-rtePosition-4 ms-rteImage-2 ms-rteStyle-Emphasis" alt="red1.jpg"
    src="__URL__" style="margin: 5px;"/></em>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;

    <a href="__URL__" target="_blank">Yellow</a>&#160;- 
    <img id="Yellow" class="ms-rtePosition-4 ms-rteImage-2 ms-rteStyle-Emphasis" alt="yellow1.jpg"
    src="__URL__" style="margin: 5px;"/>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;

    <a href="__URL__" target="_blank">White</a> &#160;-
    <img id="White" class="ms-rteImage-2 ms-rtePosition-4" alt="white.jpg"
    src="__URL__" style="margin: 5px;"/>&#160;

</html>


<style>
    a:link { text-decoration: none;
    color: #0072c6 } a:visited { text-decoration: none; color: #0072c6 } a:hover { text-decoration: underline;  } a:active { text-decoration: underline; }
</style>​

<script type="text/javascript">
//Grab data from list and post into HTML Fields
$(function() {
    green = "";
    yellow = "";
    red = "";
    white = "";

    $.ajax({
            url: "__URL__",
            headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}, 
            type: "GET", 
            cache: false,
            async: false,      

        }).success(function (data) {
            $.each(data.d.results, function(key, value) {
                 console.log(value.Title);
                 switch (value.Title) {
                    case "GREEN":
                        green += value.Description;
                        console.log("GREEN TEST" + green);
                        var gDescription = document.querySelector('#Green');
                        gDescription.title = "" + green;    
                        break;
                    case "YELLOW":
                        yellow += value.Description;
                        console.log("YELLOW TEST" + yellow);
                        var yDescription = document.querySelector('#Yellow');
                        yDescription.title = "" + yellow;   
                        break;
                    case "RED":
                        red += value.Description;
                        console.log("RED TEST" + red);
                        var rDescription = document.querySelector('#Red');
                        rDescription.title = "" + red;
                        break;
                    default:
                        white += value.Description;
                        console.log("WHITE TEST" + white);
                        var wDescription = document.querySelector('#White');
                        wDescription.title = "" + white;
                }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

This is a related question but that did not seem to fix it either:  [why can't I set an ascii reference in an img title attribute using js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890510/why-cant-i-set-an-ascii-reference-in-an-img-title-attribute-using-js)

Comment: You're looping through each of the items. Do you get an error on the console? At which item does it fail to append to the green variable? I'd put the green variable on your console log too after value.Title and value.Description. See what's being set. Without seeing the data that's causing the issue, it's difficult to suggest a solution.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that each browser will handle the title attribute differently. You need to check the data coming back from your AJAX call. And output what's being set to your variables on each loop. Use your console.log statements and you will find the error. There's no major problem in your code, per se, except for the absence of anything that sets the yellow, red or white. And the variables will continue to be appended to with each AJAX call, they're never reset to "". That may well be correct, but worth noting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
var image = document.querySelector('img');
image.title = 'Your title'; // Assigning directly to attribute.
image.setAttribute('title', 'Your other title'); // Assigning by method.
```

**This is how you could set a HTML image title attribute using javascript**

Comment: That did not work. I did var wDescription = document.querySelector('#Green'); gDescription.title = green; but all I changed is I'm grabbing it by the ID

Comment: @JWill23 `wDescription !== gDescription`

Comment: Sorry I must have copied it before I made all the changes but I meant to put gDescription and it seems to now be working but this is what the title shows up as, "<div class="ExternalClass5E84661DE4444B579A5890F6EACD974C"><p>Project has no schedule or budget impacting issues. </p></div>"